# UPDATE Changed String: How to write regex for python so that it pulls out a term and its definition?

Tags: python, regex, parsing, text

UPDATE:
As you might expect, they changed the software and so my text has changed.

Now the regex that worked does not.
Here is what worked before:
r"^ \"(?P.*?)\" refers to (?P(?:(?!^ \".*?\" refers to ).)*)"
with Multiline and dotall.

I have been working to fix it on https://regex101.com/.

I think the negative lookahead piece is failing.
I get the first term, but then it grabs everything after that.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Test String:
"Address mapping table" refers to a data structure that associates logical block addresses with physical addresses of data stored on a non-volatile memory array.  The table may be implemented as an index, a map, a b-tree, a content addressable memory (CAM), a binary tree, and/or a hash table, and the like. The address mapping table may be referred to interchangeably as a Group Allocation Table (GAT).

"Asymmetric storage media" refers to a storage media having different latencies for different storage operations. Many types of solid-state storage media (e.g., memory dies) are asymmetric; for example, a read operation may be much faster than a write/program operation, and a write/program operation may be much faster than an erase operation (e.g., reading the storage media may be hundreds of times faster than erasing, and tens of times faster than programming the storage media).

"Bit line" refers to a circuit structure configured to deliver a voltage and/or conduct current to a column of a memory array.  In one embodiment, the column comprises a NAND string or memory string and may also be referred to as channel. In one embodiment, the column is referred to as a NAND string and the NAND string comprises a channel. In one embodiment, a bit line connects to a NAND string at a drain end or drain side of the NAND string. A memory array may have one bit line for each memory cell along the word lines of the memory array.

Comment: You are trying to get the string in quote as the subject and then the non quoted part as the definition?

Comment: Are the opening and closing double quotes actually a part of the sample string?

Comment: Corret, the string in quotes is the "term" and the text after "refers to a " is the "definition".

Comment: The opening and closing quotes are NOT part of the sample string - I only included them to identify the sample string.

Comment: First off, your question is an interesting regex to solve, so thanks for the challenge! Friendly tip for asking questions on StackOverflow: I suggest editing your question with the minimum number of examples that illustrate your problem (they don't have to be real definitions, just ones that show all your use cases; ex. multilines, quotes, etc.) If anyone else finds this question, it's a rare stackoverflow user who will wade through the pages of examples you added to your question. Using the quote formatting button on that text would also help. Cheers :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I agree I should have trimmed my example to the relevant use cases.  I took the lazy path and included everything.

Comment: What's the best way to do a follow on post?

Comment: I will edit the question with the follow on post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have potentially overcomplicated the regex, but here goes:

```
regex = re.compile(
    r"^\"(?P<term>[^\"]*?)\" refers to (?P<def>(?:(?!^\"[^\"]*?\" refers to ).)*)",
    re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
```

(if you want to mess around with it interactively, you can try it out at [regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/CfqBRs/3))

```
# show what it matches:
for m in regex.finditer(contents):
    groups = m.groupdict()
    print("term: %s" % groups["term"])
    print("%s" % ("-" * 60)) # make it clear where the term ends
    d = groups["def"].strip() # regex includes blank lines
    print("%s [...] %s" % (d[:20], d[-20:])) # definitions are too long to print
    print("\n%s\n" % ("=" * 60))
```

Output:

(note that I only printed a snippet of the definition, but the full def is matched)

> ```
> term: Adjacent word line
> ------------------------------------------------------------
> a word line physical [...] r a coupling effect.
>
> ============================================================
>
> term: Bit line
> ------------------------------------------------------------
> a circuit structure  [...] of the memory array.
>
> ============================================================
>
> term: Bit line compensation voltage
> ------------------------------------------------------------
> a voltage supplied t [...]  line is programmed.
>
> ============================================================
> ```

### Regex Explanation

Flags to `re.compile`:

- [`re.MULTILINE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE): make `^` and `$` match the beginning and end of a line respectively; the default is to match the beginning/end of the entire string, which we don't want
- [`re.DOTALL`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.DOTALL): make `.` also match the newline char; we need this to match the multiline definitions

What's with all the question marks:

- `.*?`: by default, `.*` is exceptionally greedy; the question mark makes it [not greedy](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)

  > The '*', '+', and '?' qualifiers are all greedy; they match as much
  >   text as possible. Sometimes this behaviour isn’t desired; if the RE
  >   <.*> is matched against  b , it will match the entire string,
  >   and not just . Adding ? after the qualifier makes it perform the
  >   match in non-greedy or minimal fashion; as few characters as possible
  >   will be matched. Using the RE <.*?> will match only .
- `(?P<name>...)`: denotes a "capturing group" so that we can grab this matched bit by name later -- not necessary, but I find it's easier to work with.
- `(?:...)`: denotes a "non-capturing group"; this just means I needed to wrap some bit of regex in parentheses, but I didn't want it to be treated as its own group.
- `(?!...)`: the most complicated part of this --- the "[negative lookahead](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/Looking_Ahead_and_Behind.html)" expression. This means the matched text should *not* contain the enclosed regex. This prevents the definition match from continuing into the next term.
- Putting it together: `(?!^\".*?\" refers to ).)*)` says to match zero or more of any character, *unless* the characters begin with `"${some-term} refers to "`

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response.  I think the regex string you provided does the job (messy and complex, but if it does the job, I am ok with that).  I really like the regex 101 site and I appreciate your helpful explanation of the regex.  I will be doing a little more testing, but expect to mark this as answering my question.

Comment: That answer is very helpful.  I appreciate the explanation.  I thought I might need to do something like the "negative lookahead" but did not know how to do that.  I completed my testing and it works great.  thanks for the regex101.com website tip as well.  Dave.